# Vue - make axios request upon parent event

Tags: vue.js, axios

I'm basically trying to figure out how to listen for an event and call the axios request and rerender the results.

I have the following parent component (A select drop down) that has a change event that calls "appSelected"

```
<template>
    <v-app>
    <v-container>
    <v-select :items="results" item-text="name" item-value="id" v-model="selectedOption" @change="appSelected"
          :results="results"
          label="Choose Application"
          dense
     ></v-select>
     </v-container>
    </v-app>
  </template>
```

appSelected

```
appSelected() {
 Event.$emit('selected', this.selectedOption);
}
```

In my child component,I have an an Axios request that I'm trying to figure out how to call and re render when choosing a different option in the drop down. I know I shouldn't use "async mounted" but not sure what to use instead.

```
<template>
<div id="app" v-if="appselected">
<div class="card-header">
    <h5 class="card-title">Components</h5>                       
</div>
   <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-layout row wrap>
             <v-container>
          <v-flex xs12 md12 class="greyBorder blue-grey lighten-5">
                <div class="mr-4 ml-4 whiteback userGroupHeight">
              <v-layout row wrap>
                    <v-flex v-for="result in results" :key="result.name" xs6>
                      <v-checkbox light color="success" :label="result.name" v-model="result.selected">
                      </v-checkbox>
                    </v-flex>
              </v-layout>              
            </div>
          </v-flex>
        </v-container>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
</template>
<script>
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
    data () {
    return {
      results: [],
      appselected: false
    }
  },
    methods: {
    
      checkLength(index) {
      if (index < this.types.length - 1) {
        index = index + 1;
        return index;
      }
    },
  },

   async mounted() {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get('/componentpopulate', { params: { query: this.query, appid: 2 } })
        this.results = response.data
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  },

   created() {
     Event.$on('selected', (selectedOption) => {
     this.selected = selectedOption;
     this.appselected = true;
     console.log('component List application id - ' + this.selected);
    });
  }
    
}
</script>
<style scoped>
  .v-application {
      height: 250px;
  }
</style>
```

This is my created method is where I'm listening for the event

```
created() {
     Event.$on('selected', (selectedOption) => {
     this.selected = selectedOption;
     this.appselected = true;
     console.log('component List application id - ' + this.selected);
    });
  }
```

Here is where I moved to the event listener method

```
created() {
     Event.$on('selected', (selectedOption) => {
     this.selected = selectedOption;
     this.appselected = true;
     console.log('component List application id - ' + this.selected);
      
        const response = axios.get('/componentpopulate', { params: { query: this.query, appid: this.selected } })
        this.results = response.data
        console.log(response);
    });
  }
```

Here's the answer. Add the following

```
 .then((response) => {
            this.results = response.data
            console.log(response)
        });
```

Like this

```
created() {
     Event.$on('selected', (selectedOption) => {
     this.selected = selectedOption;
     this.appselected = true;
     console.log('component List application id - ' + this.selected);
      
        const response = axios.get('/componentpopulate', { params: { query: this.query, appid: this.selected } })
        
        .then((response) => {
            this.results = response.data
            console.log(response)
        });

    });
  }
```

Hope this helps some one.

Comment: If you want to call the Axios in response to the `selected` event - you should move it from the `mounted` hook to the event handler for `selected` event.

Comment: I tried that and it does make the request, but not I don't a response back. I see it in the  web dev tools.

Comment: Can you add the updated code in your question where you have moved axios call into the event handler?

Comment: Added it at the bottom. It return a promise and I don't know how to use a promise.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Use watch for your **selectedOption** and make your API calls in the parent component. However required parameters for API call should be in parent component with this way. Or in your store. After you can pass your results to your child component as props and display it there. Here is a small example:

Your Parent Component:

```js
<template>
  <div>
     <!-- your select box -->
      <Child :results="results" />
  </div>
</template>

export default {
 import Child from "./Child"
 components: {
    Child
  },
  data() {
    return {
      selectedOption : null,
      results: []
    }
  },
  watch: {
    selectedOption: async function()  {
      await axios.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then(response => {this.results = response.data})
    }
  }
}
```

And in child component:

```js
<template>
  <div>
      <div v-for="item in results" :key="item.id">
        {{item}}

      </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['results']
}
</script>
```

Comment: There is no need to `await` the result of `axios.get` in the watcher - you are already handling the promise with a `.then` clause.

Comment: i tried that and console log the results and it wasnt full of data :D after i waited for it

Comment: The watcher simply makes an AJAX request and exits. When the server replies - the promise from Axios will resolve and will update the component's data. The watcher itself does not need to wait for the server's reply.